# How can i Add Customers name on Point of Sale Reciept

Tags: odoo

How can i add customers name on Odoo 8 Pos Module to print on the receipt / Ticket

Here is the code i tried to modify in Odoo 8 POS (pos.xml file)
...static/src/xml

```
        <div class="pos-center-align"><t t-esc="new Date().toString(Date.CultureInfo.formatPatterns.shortDate + ' ' +
            Date.CultureInfo.formatPatterns.longTime)"/> <t t-esc="order.get('name')"/></div>
        <br />
        <t t-esc="widget.pos.company.name"/><br />
        Phone: <t t-esc="widget.pos.company.phone || ''"/><br />
        User: <t t-esc="widget.pos.cashier ? widget.pos.cashier.name : widget.pos.user.name"/><br />
        Shop: <t t-esc="widget.pos.shop.name"/><br />
        customer : <t t-esc="order.changed.client.name"/><br />
        <br />
        <t t-if="widget.pos.config.receipt_header">
            <div style='text-align:center'>
                <t t-esc="widget.pos.config.receipt_header" />
            </div>
            <br />
```

Comment: Oh Sorry!! It really worked... I found out that my module upgrade wasn't done properly..

Comment: A complete example could be found on this link https://www.angels-ad-pbb.com/forum/software/15964-how-to-print-customers-name-on-odoo-pos-reciept#.Wd0D9DeEDIU